# Sum of tupled values in dictionary over several keys from 2 dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, sum

I've been attempting to work on this for a bit and have been getting partially there, but not quite yet. I'm working with 2 dictionaries. My dictionaries are the following with the first dictionary's values standing for: year starting in office and years served. The second dictionary (shortened to just 3 years on there, too big to put everything on here), the key stands for the year and the values are by month (0 to 11) what the number of unemployed were:

```
pres={"Reagan": (1981, 8), "Bush":(1989, 4),
    "Bill Cliton":(1993,8,}

unemploy=   {
1989:   (6682,  6359,   6205,   6468,   6375,   6577,   6495,   6511,   6590,   6630,   6725,   6667),  
1990:   (6752,  6651,   6598,   6797,   6742,   6590,   6922,   7188,   7368,   7459,   7764,   7901),  
1991:   (8015,  8265,   8586,   8439,   8736,   8692,   8586,   8666,   8722,   8842,   8931,   9198),
1992:   (9283,  9454,   9460,   9415,   9744,   10040,  9850, 9787, 9781,   9398,   9565,   9557)   }
```

I've been trying to get the average unemployment if I were to call for one president, for example Reagan.  Where I've gotten so far:

```
def avg_unemployment_for_president (pres,unemploy,president):
    total=0 
    avg=0
    for key,value in pres.items():
        if key == president:
            firstyear= value[0]
            lastyear=value[0]+ value[1]
            if (firstyear, lastyear) in unemploy.keys():
                for x in range(firstyear,lastyear):

                    allunemp = unemploy[x]
                    listunemp=list(allunemp)
                    total= sum(listunemp)

                    return(total)

avg_unemployment_for_president(pres, unemploy "Reagan")
```

How can I get it to iterate through from the first year and add all the values in the tupled values for each year all the way until the end year? The output I'm hoping to get is a monthly unemployment average over the years served.

I've done just the monthly average for one year :

```
def avg_unemployment_for_month(unemploy,month):

    sum = 0
    avg=0
    if (0>month) or (month > 11):
        return None
    else:
        for m in unemploy.values():
            sum += m[month]
        average=sum / len(unemploy)
        avg=int(average)
        return (avg)
```

and a total unemployment for a year:

```
def total_unemployment_for_year(unemploy,year): 

    total = 0
    if year in unemploy.keys():
        allunemp = unemploy[year]

        listunemp=list(allunemp)

        totalunemp= sum(listunemp)

        return(totalunemp)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

schwobaseggl's answer is really good and short, but if you need it in function format take a look below.

```
pres = {
    "Reagan": (1981, 8),
    "Bush": (1989, 4),
    "Bill Clinton": (1993,8),
}

unemploy = {
    1989:   (6682,  6359,   6205,   6468,   6375,   6577,   6495,   6511,   6590,   6630,   6725,   6667),
    1990:   (6752,  6651,   6598,   6797,   6742,   6590,   6922,   7188,   7368,   7459,   7764,   7901),
    1991:   (8015,  8265,   8586,   8439,   8736,   8692,   8586,   8666,   8722,   8842,   8931,   9198),
    1992:   (9283,  9454,   9460,   9415,   9744,   10040,  9850,   9787,   9781,   9398,   9565,   9557),
}


def avg_unemployment_for_pres_term(name):
    if pres.get(name) is None:
        return 0

    the_pres = pres[name]

    first_year = the_pres[0]
    last_year = first_year + the_pres[1]

    years = []

    for year in range(first_year, last_year):
        unemp_rates = unemploy.get(year, (0,))
        years.append(sum(unemp_rates)/len(unemp_rates))

    return sum(years) / len(years)


def avg_unemployment_for_pres_year(name, year):
    if pres.get(name) is None:
        return 0

    the_pres = pres[name]

    unemp_rates = unemploy.get(year, (0,))
    return sum(unemp_rates)/len(unemp_rates)


print avg_unemployment_for_pres_term("Bush")  # 7958
print avg_unemployment_for_pres_year("Bush", 1989)  # 6523
```

Comment: With some tinkering and removing unnecessary bits, I got this to work perfectly for just calling one definition.

Answer (score 0):

One dict-comprehension and usage of built-in [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) will help:

```
avg_unemployment = {
    p: sum(  # sum yearly averages ...
        sum(unemploy[year])/len(unemploy[year])  # monthly average per year
        for year in range(start, start+served)   # for each year of presidency
    )/served  # ... and divide by number of years served
    for p, (start, served) in pres.iteritems()  # for each presidency
}

# for provided years:
# {'Bush': 7958}
```